# A universal formula is not equivalent to an existential formula

Tags: logic, model-theory

Suppose a formula is looks like the following:

$\forall x_1 ... \forall x_n \alpha$

Where $\alpha$ is a formula free of quantifiers.

And if $P$ is a 1-ary relation letter, then the formula $\exists x P(x)$ is not equivalent to a formula like above.

It's clear to me that this is true intuitively by observing that a formula being true for one element in a model doesn't imply it's true for all. So how could one formalize this argument?

Comment: To argue model-theoretically, let $A$ and $B$ be structures, with $B$ an extension of $A$. If a sentence $\varphi$ of the shape $\forall x_1\cdots\forall x_n \alpha$ holds in $B$, then $\varphi$ holds in $A$. This "downward" property does not hold for sentences of the form $\exists xP(x)$.

Comment: It seems to me that you should upgrade your comment to an answer.

Comment: Just one nitpick; You need to be more careful with your question. If $L=\{P\}$, $T=Cn(\emptyset)$, then this is true (I think this is implicit in your question). However, if $L=\{P\}$, you have "there exists only one element"$\subseteq{T}$, then $Cn{T}$ does contain certain things like, say $\forall{x}P(x)\iff\exists{x}P(x)$.

Comment: @DanulG Sure, and if $T$ contains $\exists x\, P(x)$, then $\exists x\, P(x)$ is equivalent to the universal formula $\top$! ($\top$ is the logical constant "true" - if you don't like including that in the language, use $\forall x\,x=x$).